# What prevents an OS to recover from a 'blue screen of death'?

Tags: operating-system, recovery, failover

If a program violates its instruction path and/or memory data the OS halts it with some message due to the program running in the 'virtual machine' like space of the OS and its unable to determine its next instruction.

The OS in tern is also a program, sharing the machine resources as any other program and can halt in a similar fashion **but** it's sometimes healthy enough to display some debugging info and blue screen. So as a programmer I'm thinking, if I can do that - emit debugging info and make the screen blue why wouldn't I be able to try to recover the OS altogether instead of requiring a cold reboot ? After all its the OS - it's supposed to be the rock solid foundation (not talking about Windows of course) of all software, if the space shuttle ran Windows then what would happen - it won't recover ?:)

So: is it only that MS hasn't taken care of trying everything to recover to the point that a reboot is not required or is it some other more deeper problem that has stop companies like MS to be unable to do that ?

Comment: I think this is a thinly disguised rant against Microsoft. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm giving MS as an example, it's also the only OS I use

Comment: every operating system can crash.  In linux its a kernel panic.  In OSX you get something akin to a bluescreen.

Comment: ... but how long has it been since you've seen a BSOD? And when was the last time you saw a BSOD caused by something _other than buggy video drivers_? If it is Microsoft bashing, it's a few years behind the times. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recover the OS for the same reasons a user-space program can't recover -- when certain types of errors are seen it means that your program is in an undefined state and therefore can't recover.  Even if the problem in some sense isn't fatal (i.e. doesn't cause the program to immediately die), it's not safe to continue because things are or are likely corrupted.

For example, be it a user-space program or the OS kernel, say a buffer overrun or an messed up pointer causes the stack to be corrupted.  How is the program supposed to recover from that?  With a blown stack when the function that is currently executing ends, where will it return to?  The return address is likely gone.  Now what?

And it's not just Microsoft.  Ever hear of a "kernel panic" in Unix?

Comment: Yes, I've hear of kernel panic, I think you are right. Actually the OS can restart from the beginning now that I think of it - and MS does sometimes. At least saving the time lean down and restart it manually. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing specific to Microsoft; Linux has a [kernel panic](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/panic.c) mechanism, OS X has a [kernel panic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMacOSX_kernel_panic.png) mechanism. I expect every non-toy operating system kernel has a panic mechanism of some sort when internal corruption is detected. The corruption could come from faulty hardware, faulty software, gamma rays hitting the memory boards just right, who knows.

The whole point behind the kernel panic is a recognition that something that shouldn't go wrong has gone wrong. What else might be invalid? Depending upon *where* the crash happened, it might not be safe to sync and unmount the filesystems because that might scribble corrupt data over *good* data on the drives.

Writing to the video card is a good way to inform the user of events (many systems have monitors attached, anyway) and writing to the video card isn't likely to corrupt on-disk data: it would take quite an error for the IOMMU or page tables to be so corrupted that they refer instead to on-disk files *and* most operating systems will refuse to write to block devices after a kernel panic to try to protect user data at all cost.

Consider what you could do to bring the system back up to a running state? You'd need to tear down all applications that might be associated with corrupted kernel data structures. You'd need to restart applications, in the right order, to bring system services back up. And a reboot is a very easy way to reliably do both those things.